# Properly block ports on openwrt

Tags: firewall, iptables, port, openwrt

I want to block certain protocols to be used, and I do this by blocking their ports such as 53.

I tried to edit `/etc/config/firewall` adding:

```
   config rule 'stopdns'
       option name 'stopdns'
       option proto 'tcpudp'
       option dest_port '53'
       option target 'DROP'
```

and `/etc/firewall.user` (when the first option did not succeed):

```
   iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j DROP
   iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
```

Same things with ports 80 and 443 to try because none of the things above worked. After each edit I run `/etc/init.d/firewall restart`.

Comment: In the iptables rules you appear to be locking the Output chain.  You probably want to block the FORWARD chain to prevent devices on the LAN sending traffic through the router.  Also, if you block the output chain, you will stop recusive DNS working from the router.

Comment: @davidgo seems not the right fix; for example `iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp/udp --dport 443 -j DROP` and still this website and any other load

Comment: Try use -I to INPUT at the start of the chain, not -A to append - there may be an earlier rule with a matching allow so your Appended rule is never reached.

Comment: @davidgo can I accept yours as answer?

Comment: Thanks for thiat - I'm pleased it worked for you. I've made it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments - The solution is to **I**nsert the iptables rule at the top of the chain, rather then **A**ppend it, so an appropriate firewall line would be:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp/udp --dport 443 -j DROP
```